# How do I reference a user profile path from within Microsoft Access SQL INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, environment-variables

I'm using a cloud storage drive to share some complicated Access databases with my coworkers.  I'd like the databases to execute directly from the local cloud storage path.

```
C:\Users\example.dude\CloudDrive\Other Folders\Main Database.accdb
C:\Users\example.dude\CloudDrive\Other Folders\Archive Database.accdb
```

I've been able to get most of it to work.  However I have some append queries in the Main Database that add data to the Archive Database.  Not the full SQL statement below, just an example.

```
::: Query in Main Database :::

INSERT INTO [Some Table] ( ID, [Other Fields] ) IN 'C:\Users\example.dude\CloudDrive\Other Folders\Archive Database.accdb\Archive Database.accdb'
SELECT [Some Table].ID, [Some Table].[Other Fields] AS etc etc etc
```

The problem is that "example.dude" is the user profile path of just one user.  How do I access the OS %USERPROFILE% in a SQL statement?

I'm averse to some sort of VBA solution that dynamically recreates the SQL; I have at least a dozen of these SQL statements and some of them are VERY lengthy.

Comment: "I'm using a cloud storage drive to share some complicated Access databases with my coworkers. I'd like the databases to execute directly from the local cloud storage path." - you're going to run into synchronization issues because this won't be ACID compliant. You're going to need a a proper cloud-hosted database.

Comment: I understand the dangers and unfortunately this is the only solution available to me in my workplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer to this exact question, but I did find a workaround.

I used the 'subst' command in Windows command line to map a drive letter to %userprofile%\CloudDrive\etc

This command isnt persistent, so I created a task in task scheduler to run at user logon and run subst.

Then all I had to do was change SQL to point to new drive letter and path.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Environ*:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Some Table] ( ID, [Other Fields] ) IN 'C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\CloudDrive\Other Folders\Archive Database.accdb\Archive Database.accdb'
```

Comment: Receive error "not a valid file name" when attempting to run the query.  When I hover over the query, the tooltip text says the database is pointing to a path with the words "Environ" in it.  I don't think it's properly escaping from SQL into VBA.  Access isn't interpreting the Environ command as we wish it to.

Comment: Yes, it can't be done this way - forgot that field and table names cannot be dynamic. So, you will have to build the complete SQL in VBA and then pass the finished SQL string to a query or recordset.